# How to Use Android Search Query (from Search Box in Action Bar) to load a specified URL with Query at end?

Tags: javascript, android, search

StackOverflow. I've spent 13 hours trying to figure this out and I feel just a bit foolish for not being able to figure it out yet. Basically what I want to do is pull the user's search query from the Action Bar's search box, and place that query at the end of a URL that I specify, then load that URL in my current webview.

Example:
User is on www.homepage.tld
User taps the search box, enters dog.
I want to put his query (dog) at the end of www.homepage.tld?search=(USER QUERY)
Then, I want to load that URL in the same webview the user is currently using (basically just like he clicked a link).

This is my current code. It's not understanding +QUERY (but I just threw it in there hoping it would work :(

```
    public boolean onKeyEnter(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && SearchView.QUERY) {
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.homepage.tld?s="+QUERY);
            return true;
        }
```

---

**Edited to Add:**

```
    package com.tabletapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.SearchView;


public class ATAActivity extends Activity {
    final Activity activity = this;
    private WebView webview; 
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);String newUA="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.2; en-us; 3ATApps0) Android/3.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Android/3.0"; // Change this to desired UA
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });        
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.homepage.tld");
    }
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
                webview.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
            // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

            // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresh:
                webview.reload ();
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                webview.loadUrl ("http://www.homepage.tld");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        public boolean onKeyEnter(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && SearchView.QUERY) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append("http://www.homepage.tld?s=");
                stringBuilder.append(SearchView.QUERY);
                String summary = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><html><body>"+ stringBuilder.toString() +" </body></html>";
                String uri = Uri.encode(summary);
                webview.loadData(uri, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyEnter(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

---

**Edited to Add:**

```
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.homepage.tld?s=" + query);
        return false;
    }
```

---

**Edited To Add:**

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        webview.loadUrl ("http://www.homepage.tld?s=" + query);
        final String TAG = "MyActivity1";
        Log.d(TAG, "index=" + 2);
        return false;
    }}
```

**This log_tag never fires. The first two (0 and 1) fire when app is loading).

Comment: Well, I guess it would not be static as it would probably be different every single time a user does a search. Basically, I own a website. I made a wevbiew app, and now I want to use the built-in Action bar search box for users to type their search query into it, then somehow take that query and append it to the end of www.homepage.tld?search=(QUERY) , then load that URL in the current webview.

Answer (score 1):

```
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // You can use the webview here.
        return true;
    }
};

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

Comment: ok, so do I put this code in place of `webview.loadUrl("http://www.homepage.tld?s="+QUERY);` ?

Comment: ok, it's saying that `QUERY cannot be resolved or is not a field` so apparently, I am not doing this search stuff correct at all. would you like the whole activity? I think I am able to do all of this from just the one activity file, right?

Comment: I've added the whole activity file. I'm not sure what you mean by 'the definition of QUERY as well' ... I'm probably headed down the wrong road... I am an amateur by far! Thank you, Coder

Comment: this is so confusing. The only thing I am understanding is that it wants to use the 'applications' global search provider... I really dont want to provide any search at all... all I want to do is grab the query from the box, append it to the end of a url, then open it in webview when the query is submitted.. I've seen this link several times and I can't find anything relevant in it :(

Comment: This QUERY is not resolving that's in my small block of code in my original question

Comment: and searchView isn't resolving to anything either

Comment: So, I can't take a search query, append it to the end of a URL, and open it in the same wevbiew when the user submits his query?

Comment: You can do it, in the `onQueryTextSubmit(String query)` method.

Comment: well, i clipped that piece of code from the link you gave, the app is working, but when i press enter, or the submit button, it does nothing. here's what i wrote:
Posted above, in an edit.

Comment: `public ATAActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`

Comment: And, it's still not giving any reaction whatsoever.

Comment: You can debug it and see if the method is called or not.

Comment: ok, if you don't mind, please lemme know what I need to do to get some debug started... I'll be googling while i wait :D

Comment: Alright, figured out how to debug, and I'm using these LOG_TAG things. I put 3 of them into the app. One when the original webview loads, a second one when the search code loads, and a third (will be posted above.) The third one, which is supposed to fire right after onQueryTextSubmit, NEVER fires.

Comment: You just need to set a breakpoint, right click on the first line of the onTextSubmit method and then choose debug from the menu, then click whatever you wanna click and see if the debugger stops at your breakpoint, then you step through the code with F5/F6 (F6 skips going into methods) and check the variables values to see what's going on. I have to go, so good luck.

Comment: In fires if you implement the listener, I think you have to override them all in order to eliminate the abstract requirement. Good luck. Must sleep.

Comment: Not sure what "all" you're suggesting I override, but I've tried everything I could think of over the past hour and nothing is making them fire. I've now figured out that it's not detecting the change in text in the search box, AS WELL AS not detecting the button press to actually execute the 'query'.

Comment: Also, this 'listener' is implemented... I did what you requested up in the activity declaration:
`public abstract class ATAActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {`